# WinHTTP and Websocket

Tags: c++, http, websocket, winhttp

I am trying to use WinHTTP to connect to server, unfortunately when i am trying to upgrade the protocol from http to webscoket, the API WinHttpSetOption fails.

```
hSessionHandle    = WinHttpOpen(L"WebSocket sample",WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,NULL,  NULL,0);
hConnectionHandle = WinHttpConnect(hSessionHandle, L"localhost",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);
hRequestHandle    = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnectionHandle,L"GET",L"/ws",NULL,NULL,NULL,  0);

// Request protocol upgrade from http to websocket.
fStatus = WinHttpSetOption(hRequestHandle,WINHTTP_OPTION_UPGRADE_TO_WEB_SOCKET,NULL,0);
if (!fStatus)
{
   dwError = GetLastError();
   goto quit;
}
```

`fStatus` returns FALSE, with `GetLastError` returning error code 12009 which says

> **ERROR_WINHTTP_INVALID_OPTION**
>   12009: A request to WinHttpQueryOption or WinHttpSetOption specified an invalid option value.

The above code is taken from the [Microsoft WinHttp WebSocket demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WinHTTP-WebSocket-sample-50a140b5) *([new GitHub home](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/WinhttpWebsocket/cpp/WinhttpWebsocket.cpp))*

My system is Windows 7. Does the OS need to be Windows 8 or above? Any clues of this API fail?

Comment: Since the upgrade completion function, [`WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707326(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly specifies Windows 8 as the minimal platform, I'm going to go ahead and say yeah, you need Windows 8 or beyond.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig....Is there any way we can use websockets with winHttp in Win 7?

Answer (score 3):

There's a great C++ WebSocket library here that works in Windows 7, its header-only and uses just boost. It comes with example code and documentation:
http://vinniefalco.github.io/

Here's a complete program that sends a message to the echo server. This will work in Windows 7 for you.

```
#include <beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <beast/buffers_debug.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "echo.websocket.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "80"}));

    using namespace beast::websocket;

    // WebSocket connect and send message using beast
    stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> ws(sock);
    ws.handshake(host, "/");
    ws.write(boost::asio::buffer("Hello, world!"));

    // Receive WebSocket message, print and close using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    opcode op;
    ws.read(op, sb);
    ws.close(close_code::normal);
    std::cout <<
        beast::debug::buffers_to_string(sb.data()) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working?

I found that using "echo.websocket.org" was great for testing.

Also these are the values that worked for me:

```
WinHttpOpenRequest(
  IN HINTERNET hConnect,
  IN LPCWSTR   pwszVerb,           --- "GET"
  IN LPCWSTR   pwszObjectName,     --- NULL
  IN LPCWSTR   pwszVersion,        --- NULL
  IN LPCWSTR   pwszReferrer,       --- WINHTTP_NO_REFERER
  IN LPCWSTR   *ppwszAcceptTypes,  --- WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES
  IN DWORD     dwFlags             --- 0

);
```